# Slow Scrolling on Ace Text Editor For Mobile Touch Screen Devices

Tags: javascript, mobile, ace-editor

I'm trying to get The JavaScript code editor [ACE](http://ace.ajax.org) to work on a mobile device.

```
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/twilight");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/css");
```

You can find the full code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GRNcN/)

The vertical scrolling does not seem to respond at all for any mobile device and it's lagging a lot. How can I make it more responsive?

Comment: I have noticed that as well. If I attach a keyboard and mouse to my Nexus 10 via USB OTG, I can scroll with the scroll wheel or arrow keys. A lite/mobile version supporting touch would be nice, but I'm not aware of one.

Comment: You should file a bug in [ace's git repository](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/) ([click here to file a new bug](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/new))

Comment: Khan's editor is based on ACE, don't know if it works better or if Resig&co have created something - if they havent, perhaps they might be also interested.  http://khan.github.io/live-editor/demos/simple/

Comment: Which mobile devices have you tried?  There's a **wide** variety of devices out there with different capabilities.

Comment: looks like there've been fixes for these throughout the years, https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/1629 (2013), https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/1726 (2015), https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/3350 (2017)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, codemirror hasn't had any performance issues for ages, so try to use that. Here's your jsfiddle but with codemirror instead: https://jsfiddle.net/DerpMarine/j54gfecL/16/

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.39.2/codemirror.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.39.2/codemirror.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.39.2/mode/css/css.js"></script>
</body>
<script>

var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror(function(elt) {
  document.getElementById('editor').parentNode.replaceChild(elt, document.getElementById('editor'));
},{
  mode:  "css",
  theme: "custom", // https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#option_theme and https://codemirror.net/theme/
  value: document.getElementById('editor').value
});
</script>
```

https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html

Comment: Question is very specific to Ace. Swapping Ace with CodeMirror might have advantages but its not relevant to the ask and also not simple to just swap out one editor with other.